# Business Expenses prior to initial set up of business (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, small-business

I'm setting myself up as a sole-trader in the UK, as a Life Coach. I hope to put out my first advertising and get my first paying clients over the course of the next month, or so.

It's clear to me that I can claim some costs as business expenses prior to actually doing business.

E.g.

- Buying Domain Name
- Setting up website
- Initial advertising
- Buying a business phone
- etc. etc.

These are all things that specifically relate to setting up my business.

As I trade I will buy books relevant to my trade to continue learning and keeping abreast of my industry.

It's clear to me that I should claim those books as business expenses too.

But I've been buying books about the industry as I headed towards my free-lancing, for the last several months - **Can I claim those too?**

A month ago, I bought a book *about* setting up a company, specifically to aid with this process. **Can I claim that as an expense?**

I have just (in the last 3 months) completed a 2-year Masters in Positive Psychology, which is my relevant qualification for doing this. *If* I'd done that whilst I was already a sole-trader, I would expect to treat this as an expense. But I *actually* did it before being a sole-trader. **Can I claim *that* as a business expense?**

More generally, how do I work out what I am and am not allowed to claim? Does HMRC have a guide for this?

Supposing I AM allowed to claim this, then how do I do it? Do I have to claim it in the first financial year I trade? (Which would be a shame since I likely won't earn enough to pay tax before April, in which case the expenses are irrelevant) Or am I allowed to back-claim it in the 18/19 financial year?

Comment: IMO these are questions for your accountant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can claim expenses during your 1st financial year, with different limitations for different things.

You can only claim money from taxes you are going to pay - the UK government does not actually give you money, except tax credits I suppose.

The claim happens on the sum you owe to the government in form of taxes, for a specific financial year and will never be more than the amount of taxes you owe.

If you are self-employed please refer to:

https://www.gov.uk/expenses-if-youre-self-employed

If you are planning running a limited company:

https://www.gov.uk/running-a-limited-company

Also as pointed by **Rupert Morrish** in the comment, if you were doing business for a while, you can carry the losses forward from the previous financial year(s), up to 5 years.

You can find out more about carrying losses forward in the UK using the link below:

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/losses-hs227-self-assessment-helpsheet/hs227-losses-2017

Comment: "you can only claim money from taxes you are going to pay the same year" Does the UK no longer let you carry forward losses?

Comment: Good point @RupertMorrish.
I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but know a bit about taxes and quite a lot about business. Right off the top of my head I would say that any and all purchases made that help or enable you to start your business or make money can be claimed in expenses.

[This resource](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/480-expenses-and-benefits-a-tax-guide) I've found that should help you out more. It's through the government so you know it'll be lengthy and wordy but also your most accurate source.